# Interpretation auto.arima results in R

Tags: r, package, time-series, forecasting, model-fitting

As a beginner, I am trying to understand the auto.arima function in the R forecasting package.

Particularly, I am interested in the selection based on the information criteria.
For instance, I set `ic=c("aicc","aic", "bic")`.
I then obtain the best fitting model with AIC, AICc, and BIC.

I also obtain a certain output value for every tested model, e.g. -18661.23 for (1,1,1); -18451.12 for (1,1,2) etc. If e.g. (1,1,1) is the selected model with lowest output value, this value is not equal to the given AIC, AICc, or BIC.

In simple words, how do I interpret the output value of every model? Is it a parallely weighted AIC, AICc, and BIC?

P.S.: I really tried to understand the documentation but it is hard for me to read.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by the "output value"?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 
My output values: 
...
ARIMA(2,0,2) with zero mean     : -17391.46;
ARIMA(2,0,2) with non-zero mean : -17413.33;
ARIMA(2,0,3) with zero mean     : -17389.61;
ARIMA(2,0,3) with non-zero mean : -17411.40;
...

ARIMA(2,0,2) with non-zero mean 

Coefficients:
AIC=-17413.33   AICc=-17413.29   BIC=-17356.3

How do I interpret the output value for each model in the stepwise selection? E.g. (2,0,2) output value of -17413.33 is identical to the AIC. Is it always the AIC, even tough I specified  ic=c("aic","aicc", "bic")? How are the AICc and the BIC taken into account?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell, by "output value" you mean the value printed when you use `auto.arima` with `trace=TRUE`.

These values are the AIC (or AICc or BIC) for each model tried. An approximation is used during the search to speed things up, so the value printed may different slightly from the value returned, which is calculated without the approximation.

The argument `ic` determines which information criterion will be used. For example, setting `ic="bic"` means that the BIC is used in selecting the model. By default, `ic="aicc"`.

In a function definition, an argument with default value equal to a vector of values is often a shorthand for showing what the possible values that argument can take, with the first value in the vector equal to the default. In this case, the function definition contains `ic = c("aicc", "aic", "bic")` meaning that `ic` can take only one of those three values, and the default is `aicc` if `ic` is not explicitly passed.